# How to deserialise JSON to FHIR valueset resource in .net

Tags: c#, hl7-fhir

I'm having trouble casting a a response from a valueset expansion to the valueset resource object in c#.

I'm currently using RestSharp, the REST call is successful, and the following outputs the expected JSON.

```
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I've tried

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ValueSet>(response.Content);
```

But it produces a null object. I'm sure I'm making some rookie error, and perhaps should look into using the Hl7.Fhir.Rest instead of RestSharp?

Comment: The Hl7.Fhir.Rest is the official .Net library for FHIR, and has methods for deserializing to correct FHIR json, so yes, I would recommend to take a look at that.

Comment: Thanks @MirjamBaltus, the official library does make things much easier. the official library is really good. I guess my original intent was to use RestSharp, because I'd be (possibly) using it for other non-fhir purposes.

Comment: I've appended my answer to "prefer the Hl7.Fhir.Rest" library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did end up being able to deserialise the RestSharp JSON response, by creating custom ValueSet class (I just used http://json2csharp.com/ for my experiment).

However I took @Mirjam's advice, and used **Hl7.Fhir.Rest** instead (And ValueSet class from **HL7.Fhir.Model** - which contains so much more goodness than could be achieved using a custom class.

```
// using using Hl7.Fhir.Model;
// using Hl7.Fhir.Rest;

const string Endpoint = "https://ontoserver.csiro.au/stu3-latest";
var client = new FhirClient(Endpoint);

//uri for the value set to be searched, and text filter         
var filter = new FhirString("inr");
var vs_uri = new FhirUri("http://snomed.info/sct?fhir_vs=refset/1072351000168102");

ValueSet result = client.ExpandValueSet(vs_uri, filter);
 
//Write out the display term of the first result.
Console.WriteLine(result.Expansion.Contains.FirstOrDefault().Display);
```

There's a couple of other approaches, that support additional parameters...

Code available - https://gist.github.com/MattCordell/32f3c62b4e66bd1ecb17b65f2f498acb

Comment: Matt, would you (pretty please) add your namespaces and nuget packages to your answer?  I don't know where FhirClient is coming from.

Comment: Thanks @granadaCoder. I had mentioned the namespace, but I've edited so it's a bit more obvious now. (Hl7.Fhir.Rest) and provided a link to complete code. I used the STU3 package you link to below. I blogged my learnings here http://snoyowie.com/2018/03/exploring-fhir-value-set-expansion-in-net/

Comment: #petPeeve.   when its obvious, "var" is ok (to me)   var emp = new Employee();      But when it isn't obvious, and especially with code/teaching samples, i don't like "var".....could you update your sample to show exactly what datatype "result" is .. as in "result = client.ExpandValueSet......"   this a nitpick to an otherwise great answer (and I just read your blog post)

Answer (score 5):

First, you should check out

A REST client for working with FHIR-compliant servers;

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hl7.Fhir.R4/4.3.0

(and "examples" via unit-tests here)

https://github.com/FirelyTeam/firely-net-sdk/blob/release/4.0.0-r4/src/Hl7.Fhir.Core.Tests/Rest/FhirClientTests.cs

You should try really hard to use the above.  It avoids "re-invent the wheel syndrome", especially "un happy paths" and how fhir-servers handle paging.

HOWEVER, if you do not follow the above advice:

You can use HttpClient and https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hl7.Fhir.DSTU2/  (or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hl7.Fhir.STU3/) ( or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hl7.Fhir.R4/ ) (or whatever is the latest)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/* magic ones */
using Hl7.Fhir.Serialization;
using Hl7.Fhir.Model;

        string url = "https://www.somebody.com/FHIR/api/Patient?given=Jason&family=Smith";

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    string responseString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    /* Hl7.Fhir.DSTU2  \.nuget\packages\hl7.fhir.dstu2\0.96.0 */

                    FhirJsonParser fjp = new FhirJsonParser(); /* there is a FhirXmlParser as well */
                    /* You may need to Parse as something besides a Bundle depending on the return payload */
                    Hl7.Fhir.Model.Bundle bund = fjp.Parse<Hl7.Fhir.Model.Bundle>(responseString);
                    if (null != bund)
                    {
                        Hl7.Fhir.Model.Bundle.EntryComponent ec = bund.Entry.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (null != ec && null != ec.Resource)
                        {
                            /* again, this may be a different kind of object based on which rest url you hit */
                            Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient pat = ec.Resource as Hl7.Fhir.Model.Patient;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```